# Existence of infinite subsequence of trees with a subtree contained in the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Assume a statement:

> For every infinite sequence of rooted trees $\{T\}_{i=0}^\infty$ there is an index $j\geq0$
>   such that there are infinitely many trees in $\{T\}_{i=0}^\infty$ which contains $T_j$ as
>   subtree.

True or false? Could it possibly relate to [The hydra game](http://math.andrej.com/2008/02/02/the-hydra-game/)?

I need it for an extension of [Dickson's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_lemma) (and that I need for an extension of minimal coverability tree for membrane systems with active membranes).

Comment: If the answer is True (I hope so) and the proof is non-trivial, you will be awarded with a honorable mention in my dissertation thesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the sequence of trees of which the first three are shown below?  None is a subtree of any other.

[image]