# Existence of infinite subsequence of trees assuming two tree operations

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Assume two operations on rooted trees:

1. **contract an edge**: choose an edge $E$, join two vertices adjacent to $E$
2. **grow a leaf**: choose any vertex and connect it to a new leaf

Starting with any rooted tree, using these operations we get an infinite sequence of trees.

> Does the sequence always contain a tree $T$ such that there is
>   infinitely many trees in the sequence with $T$ as a subgraph?

It is a variation of question [Existence of infinite subsequence of trees with a subtree contained in the sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045777/existence-of-infinite-subsequence-of-trees-with-a-subtree-contained-in-the-seque) with added limitation on succesive items in the sequence. This variation now maybe could relate to [The hydra game](http://math.andrej.com/2008/02/02/the-hydra-game/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your operations to be 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2, then such an order will ensure that all your trees will have either $n$ or $(n+1)$ vertices, and since there is only a finite number of non-isomorphic trees of size $n$, you will get infinitely many copies of at least one of them.

On the other hand, if the order of operations is unconstrained, then an adaptation of [the example of Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1045836/26306) still works:

[image: a sequence of non-isomorphic trees]

and so on...

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$